# Python instance attribute takes initial value from class attribute with the same name?

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
class bambino(object):
    counter = 7
    def __init__(self):
        print("bambino.counter is self.counter ?", bambino.counter is self.counter)
        self.counter += 1
        print("bambino.counter is self.counter ?", bambino.counter is self.counter)

bambi1 = bambino()
print ("bambi1.counter:", bambi1.counter)
print ("bambino.counter:", bambino.counter)
```

prints:

```
bambino.counter is self.counter ? True
bambino.counter is self.counter ? False
bambi1.counter: 8
bambino.counter: 7
```

I understand that by doing `self.counter += 1` *counter* becomes an attribute of the instance not of the class.

But why did `bambi1.counter` take it's initial value from `bambino.counter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an attribute is not found in an object, it gets looked up higher in the hierarchy, first in its class, and then, if not found, in the superclasses.

`self.counter += 1` is equivalent to `self.counter = self.counter + 1`. So to assign the `bambi1.counter`, Python first needs to get the value of `bambi1.counter`. Since the `bambi1` does not initially have a `counter`, python doesn't find it and has to look it up in its class.

PS: Please capitalize your class names.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the behavior is different for mutable objects when they are just modified and not reassigned.

Comment: It's not the mutability per se, it's that some types have `+=` overloaded to mutate the object in-place instead.

Comment: Ah I didn't even think of the `+=` case but more generic cases like `foo = {}` in the class and then `self.foo[..] = ..`

Comment: This isn't a problem if you already understand that mutating an object is fundamentally different from replacing it.